# Getting values from a table that fit criteria from another table - Rails 4

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1

```
Ruby 2.0
Rails 4.1
MySQL
```

I have the following models:

```
Agent with the following fields:
id
name
```

and Payment with the following fields:

```
id
agent_id
amount
```

What is the ActiveRecord syntax to get the list of unique agents who have a payment larger than zero. I tried a number of variations, but they're all producing non-unique lists.

In agents.rb, I have:

```
has_many :payments
```

In payments.rb, I have the following:

```
belongs_to :agents
```

## Solution:

```
  @agents = Agent.joins(:payments)
    .where("payments.amount > 0")
    .group("agents.id")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work? (my ruby is a little rusty)

```
Agent.all(:joins => :payments, :group => :id, :conditions => ["payment.amount > 0"] )
```

Comment: No, I get wrong number of arguments. How does ActiveRecord know that payments.agent_id should be equal to agents.id?

Comment: You should have a `has_many` relationship between `Agent` and `Payment`- that is where the FK gets defined

Comment: I do have in the payments model: belongs_to agent and in the agent model: has_many payments. My IDE (RubyMine) is telling me that I am missing an argument

Comment: See answer in my edits. I will give you credit for this seeing that you gave me the hint to use :joins

Comment: thanks - the trick is the `group` clause - this is what *unifiques* the agents